# Xamarin Control Template with two pickers events handle

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a xamarin control template with two pickers and is added in app.xml, I use that template in two pages "Home & Detail", i want to:

1. How to maintain pickers selected index across all pages that use this template.
2. How to handle selectedindexchange event for both pickers across all pages, ex: (When index change set label text with selected text)

PS: my pickers items sources will be set at run-time from my model. and based on 1st picker selection item source for 2nd picker will change.

**app.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="SimpleTheme.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="ActiveProfileTemplate">
                <Grid Padding="5,0,0,0" BackgroundColor="#f7f6fb">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.1*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.8*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <BoxView Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                    <Picker x:Name="FirstPicker" Title="FirstPicker" SelectedIndex="{TemplateBinding Parent.FirstPickerSelectedIndex}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="180" FontSize="Small" TextColor="#214189">
                        <Picker.Items>
                            <x:String>FirstPicker_1</x:String>
                            <x:String>FirstPicker_2</x:String>
                            <x:String>FirstPicker_3</x:String>
                            <x:String>FirstPicker_4</x:String>
                            <x:String>FirstPicker_5</x:String>
                        </Picker.Items>
                    </Picker>
                    <Picker x:Name="SecondPicker" Title="SecondPicker" SelectedIndex="{TemplateBinding Parent.SecondPickerSelectedIndex}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="210" FontSize="Small" TextColor="#214189" >
                        <Picker.Items>
                            <x:String>SecondPicker_1</x:String>
                            <x:String>SecondPicker_2</x:String>
                            <x:String>SecondPicker_3</x:String>
                            <x:String>SecondPicker_4</x:String>
                            <x:String>SecondPicker_5</x:String>
                        </Picker.Items>
                    </Picker>
                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**HomePage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="SimpleTheme.HomePage">
    <ContentView x:Name="contentView" Padding="0,20,0,0" ControlTemplate="{StaticResource ActiveProfileTemplate}">
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <Label Text="Welcome to the HomePage!" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
            <Label x:Name="lbl_firstpicker" Text="First Picker Selected Item" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="DarkRed"/>
            <Label x:Name="lbl_secondpicker" Text="Second Picker Selected Item" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="DarkRed"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView>
</ContentPage>
```

**HomePage.cs**

```
public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty FirstPickerSelectedIndexProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        "FirstPickerSelectedIndex",
        typeof(int),
        typeof(HomePage),
        2);
    public static readonly BindableProperty SecondPickerSelectedIndexProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        "SecondPickerSelectedIndex",
        typeof(int),
        typeof(HomePage),
        3);

    public int FirstPickerSelectedIndex => (int)GetValue(FirstPickerSelectedIndexProperty);
    public int SecondPickerSelectedIndex => (int)GetValue(SecondPickerSelectedIndexProperty);

    public HomePage()
    {
            InitializeComponent();
     }
}
```

**DetailPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SimpleTheme.DetailPage">
    <ContentView x:Name="contentView" Padding="0,20,0,0" ControlTemplate="{StaticResource ActiveProfileTemplate}">
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <Label Text="Welcome to the DetailPage!" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
            <Label x:Name="lbl_firstpicker" Text="First Picker Selected Item" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="Teal" />
            <Label x:Name="lbl_secondpicker" Text="Second Picker Selected Item" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="Teal" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView>
</ContentPage>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMPKX.png)
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yg9sL.png)

Comment: does it work now  ?

Comment: Yup it works, thanks a lot for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i dont find a good way to set up a listener, i use a custom `ContentView` to contain the ControlTemplate's layout like this :

**MyView.xaml**:

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="App5.MyView">
  <ContentView.Content>
    <Grid Padding="5,0,0,0" BackgroundColor="#f7f6fb">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.1*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="0.8*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <BoxView Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <Picker x:Name="FirstPicker" Title="FirstPicker"    Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="180" FontSize="Small" TextColor="#214189" >
        </Picker>
        <Picker x:Name="SecondPicker" Title="SecondPicker"   Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="210" FontSize="Small" TextColor="#214189" >
        </Picker>
        <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    </Grid>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

**MyView.xaml.cs**:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class MyView : ContentView
 {

    public MyView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<FirstModel> listFirstModel = new List<FirstModel>();
        listFirstModel.Add(new FirstModel { Key = "Pl", Description = "DescPl" });
        listFirstModel.Add(new FirstModel { Key = "Ps", Description = "DescPs" });
        listFirstModel.Add(new FirstModel { Key = "En", Description = "DescEn" });
        listFirstModel.Add(new FirstModel { Key = "H", Description = "DescH" });

        List<SecondModel> listSecondModel = new List<SecondModel>();
        listSecondModel.Add(new SecondModel { FirstModelKey = "Pl", Key = "Pl1", Description = "SecondModelPl1" });
        listSecondModel.Add(new SecondModel { FirstModelKey = "Pl", Key = "Pl2", Description = "SecondModelPl2" });
        listSecondModel.Add(new SecondModel { FirstModelKey = "Pl", Key = "Pl3", Description = "SecondModelPl3" });

        listSecondModel.Add(new SecondModel { FirstModelKey = "Ps", Key = "Ps1", Description = "SecondModelPs1" });
        listSecondModel.Add(new SecondModel { FirstModelKey = "Ps", Key = "Ps2", Description = "SecondModelPs2" });
        listSecondModel.Add(new SecondModel { FirstModelKey = "Ps", Key = "Ps3", Description = "SecondModelPs3" });

        listSecondModel.Add(new SecondModel { FirstModelKey = "En", Key = "En1", Description = "SecondModelEn1" });
        listSecondModel.Add(new SecondModel { FirstModelKey = "En", Key = "En2", Description = "SecondModelEn2" });
        listSecondModel.Add(new SecondModel { FirstModelKey = "En", Key = "En3", Description = "SecondModelEn3" });

        listSecondModel.Add(new SecondModel { FirstModelKey = "H", Key = "H1", Description = "SecondModelH1" });
        listSecondModel.Add(new SecondModel { FirstModelKey = "H", Key = "H2", Description = "SecondModelH2" });
        listSecondModel.Add(new SecondModel { FirstModelKey = "H", Key = "H3", Description = "SecondModelH3" });


        foreach (FirstModel fm in listFirstModel)
        {
            FirstPicker.Items.Add(fm.Description);
        }
        FirstPicker.SelectedIndexChanged += (sender, e) => {

            SecondPicker.Items.Clear();

            string key = listFirstModel[FirstPicker.SelectedIndex].Key;
            foreach (SecondModel sm in listSecondModel.FindAll(o => o.FirstModelKey == key))
                SecondPicker.Items.Add(sm.Description);

        };

       // use MessagingCenter to get the SelectedIndex and set it
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<string, int>("firstpicker", "indext", (sender, args) => {
            FirstPicker.SelectedIndex = args;
        });
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<string, int>("secondpicker", "indext", (sender, args) => {
            SecondPicker.SelectedIndex = args;
        });
    }


}
```

**HomePage.xaml**:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App5"
         x:Class="App5.HomePage">

    <StackLayout x:Name="ss" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
    //use the custom contentView
    <local:MyView x:Name="mv"></local:MyView>
    <Label Text="Welcome to the HomePage!" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <Label x:Name="lbl_firstpicker" Text="First Picker Selected Item" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="DarkRed"/>
        <Label x:Name="lbl_secondpicker" Text="Second Picker Selected Item" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="DarkRed"/>
    <Button Text="todetail" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
</StackLayout>
```

**HomePage.xaml.cs**:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
{
    private int firstSelectedIndex;
    private int secondSelectedIndex;

    public HomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //find the picker control and set listener
        Picker p = mv.FindByName<Picker>("FirstPicker");
        Picker s = mv.FindByName<Picker>("SecondPicker");
        p.SelectedIndexChanged += FirstPicker_SelectedIndexChanged;
        s.SelectedIndexChanged += SecondPicker_SelectedIndexChanged;
    }
    void FirstPicker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var picker = (Picker)sender;
        firstSelectedIndex = picker.SelectedIndex;
        if (firstSelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            lbl_firstpicker.Text = picker.Items[firstSelectedIndex];
        }

    }
    void SecondPicker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var picker = (Picker)sender;
        secondSelectedIndex = picker.SelectedIndex;

        if (secondSelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            lbl_secondpicker.Text = picker.Items[secondSelectedIndex];
        }
    }
    // navigation to detailpage and notice Picker to set the selected indext
    async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailPage());
        MessagingCenter.Send<string, int>("firstpicker", "indext", firstSelectedIndex);
        MessagingCenter.Send<string, int>("secondpicker", "indext", secondSelectedIndex);
    }
}
```

**Model**: Linkage is realized through key

```
class FirstModel
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public FirstModel()
    {
    }
}

class SecondModel
{
    public string FirstModelKey { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public SecondModel()
    {
    }
}
```

**DetailsPage** is similar to **HomePage**

Comment: When i try to add the above approach in a project contains a Master Page and call `MessagingCenter.Send` in `protected override void OnDisappearing()` in views instead of `Button_Clicked` i face a weird behavior:
In `DetailsPage` Choose from first picker `DescPl` and from second picker `SecondModelPl2` then navigate to `HomePage` selected index of second picker will be 0 instead of 1 and this behavior is reproducible by different ways.
All code is same as above

Comment: dou you  select picker in `DetailsPage` and then navigate to `HomePage` ?if yes ,you should call `MessagingCenter.Send` in `protected override void OnDisappearing()` in `DetailsPage` .

Comment: I do call it in both pages, i posted my code on this link https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/150904/control-template-with-two-pickers-events-handle#latest both pages have same code

Comment: you should call it in the page which you would select the picker,if you call in the page which dont select the picker,it would send a  default value（0）

Comment: I need to maintain index between Detail & Home pages and also can change it from any of them. Your main approach achieve that but when i add a master page and start using onDisappearing () behavior didn't work correctly. Specially with the scenario i posted in 1st comment & other scenarios as if i select 2nd item in 1st picker it works fine.

Comment: you could make a breakpoint to have a look ，whether MessageCenter receive the pass value.